# Using regex to match the name of the process using netstat -nb python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, networking, netstat

I am using python 3 and trying to get the name of the process, using netstat -nb.
I managed to get using subprocess moudle the following string:

> '  TCP    192.168.1.22:65477     212.55.188.116:443     ESTABLISHED\n [WinStore.App.exe]'

My question is, how can i get using regex the name of the process "WinStore.App.exe".

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\[([^\[\]]+)\]
```

And use the first group. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ztHSfb/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = ' TCP 192.168.1.22:65477 212.55.188.116:443 ESTABLISHED\n [WinStore.App.exe]'

rx = re.compile(r'\[([^\[\]]+)\]')

apps = [m.group(1) for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(apps)
```

This yields

```
['WinStore.App.exe']
```

Answer (score 0):

@Yuval
I don't install the net stat package locally ,but I am pretty sure the logic of extracting the process name is run successfully as attached in the screenshot .
I am tested on regex101 .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. It assumes there are no ~ characters in your input string and assumes no more than 200 characters precede the brackets, no more than 99 characters within the brackets, and no more than 200 characters following the brackets

```
    str = ' TCP 192.168.1.22:65477 212.55.188.116:443 ESTABLISHED\n [WinStore.App.exe]'
    newstr = re.sub("^[^~]{0,200}\[([^~]{0,99})\][^~]{0,200}$" ,  r"\1",    str     )
```